# How to know Band overview resolutions available using gdal

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, multi-band, band

I want to know bands resolution. Is there any way using GDAL that we can see the resolution of bands?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Your question is very brief so I recommend reviewing http://meta.G&FH.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get raster [GeoTransform](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#adf94718221d264fc798043e13adf8c8f) - see details here: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html
2. Get [needed overview](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a00bba92f9b0c9e56e724ed07aca451b1)
3. Overview resolution by X axis = Overview X size * X Pixel Size / Raster X size

   Where X Pixel size is adfGeoTransform[1]

The Y resolution can be fetched same way.

P.S. this is works for normal case (no rotation in adfGeoTransform). In case of rotation you need to warp image (see [GDALAutoCreateWarpedVRT](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarper_8h.html)).

Comment: And if ready made tool is preferred, use gdalinfo which reports the pixel size and overviews, if they exist.